# Pass node parameter to gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp, stack-overflow

I have switched from Uglify2 to Uglify3 and I got an error about stack size exceeded. Google pointed me to call node with --stack-size=value argument. But how can I do it with a gulp script?

If I had a normal script I would do: $ node --stack-size=2048 script.js

I have a gulp task like: $ gulp build

How can I pass a parameter to node then?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it

```
$ node --stack-size=10000 ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip. For getting vscode to build for me on Node 10 (v10.16.3 via nvm), this slight variation of your provided command did the trick to fix my similar error:  `node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/gulp compile`

Comment: Just to follow up, for the record, I just realized that I used nvm incorrectly when attempting to set my node version, and it actually referenced some version of Node 12 (not Node 10), which is currently unsupported for building vscode, which is why I faced that error... In case that comment were to confuse anybody down the road.